# Javascript Dynamic variable names not working

Tags: javascript

I have a table in a form with a list of products where there is an input for each (let's call it 'pc'). Each input is named as 'pc' and product id with an id as the same. IE: 'pc100', 'pc101', etc.  Each input has an onkeyup event to call a function to populate a price where I pass the product id (`onkeyup='myfunction(100)`  The function receives the id but I cannot configure the javascript to that id. I will have the rest of the code as long as I can get the dynamic variable name.  The internet is full of all kinds of things like eval() and window[] and I have tried every possible combination I can think of/find. I know it's possible to get this to work. So...how can I get this alert to work?

Most the results I will give me 'pc100' when I need 'Heres my test'

```
function myfunction(idpro) {
    var pc331 = 'Heres my test';
    alert( "pc" + idpro );

}
```

Comment: You cannot access locally scoped variables with a variable name. That can only be used on object properties, and it would be done differently to what you're trying.

Comment: `eval("pc"+idpro)` should work.

Comment: @Jeff Suggesting `eval` without issuing a strong warning of using it is ***really bad advice***.

Comment: An alternative would be to have an object or array named `pc` and do `pc[idpro]`

Comment: @CrayonViolent Given the example we have it would be `obj['pc'+idpro]`.

Comment: @connexo splitting hairs, but fair enough!

Comment: OP seemed nonplused about using it, since he tried to use it already.  I agree, eval is generally a bad implementation.

Comment: alert( obj['pc'+idpro] ); errored... Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Don't use dynamic variable names. Do use look-ups in data structures:

```
function f(id) {
  var pc = {
    331: "Here's my test"
  }

  console.log(pc[id]);
}
```

Dynamic variables are a huge problem, especially from a security perspective. If you were naive and used `eval` someone could construct an `id` value that executes arbitrary JavaScript and then you have an [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) problem.

Comment: Basically I can grab the data I need and want to put it into the price with that id. IE: ```document.getElementById(pc331).value=pc331;```

Comment: What is `pc311` in this case? A simple string? Also consider using `$('#' + pc311).val(pc311)` if you have jQuery-like selectors. You're going to have to explain your use case in more detail because it's really hazy right now. Your example text of `'Heres my test'` is not a valid CSS ID.

Comment: Input is name='pc311' id='pc311' and populates with a price of 129.00.  If the customer is buying more than 5 there is a price in the database that the function can grab and put into that input.  Let's say the volume price is 119.00. The form populates with all products ordered over the last 3 months so there could be 20-50 products each with a price and quantity.  Hence, each product has an input called qty + idpro and pc + idpro.  When there is a change in quantity and over 5 the function needs to get the new price and put it into the correct pc input.

Comment: However, currently I have the 'pc' and the id (311) but cannot get them put together to update input 'pc311'

Comment: `'pc' + id` gives you that string. Not sure what else you're asking for.

Comment: That gives me 'pc311' not 'heres my test'

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're doing? This question would benefit from some sample HTML on which `getElementById` will operate, plus an example ofthe values being passed in to the function. `heres my test` is not an ID value.

Comment: ```function myfunction(idpro){var pc331 = 125; alert(pcidpro);}``` Where the value of idpro is 331, set pc331 = 125, alert the value of pc331.  No matter the trial the value displayed is either 'pc331' or it errors. The value 'pc331' is wrong, it should display 125.

Comment: Read my answer here and adapt it to your needs. If you want different values, use different values. Everything you need is present in this answer.

Comment: By getting the value to display then I will have the correct syntax so that I can update the input id -> 'pc331'.  The only thing that worked is the eval.  My javascript knowledge is basic, what is the issue with eval?